# Hide Folders Elevated Privileges TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I have elevated privileges on my companies TFS server so I can assist other teams when necessary (from working on projects to building folder structures and binding projects). This gives my source control tree a huge repository of directories. I consistently work with a select few, and it would be great if when I went to view source control I only saw the directories I've defined in my "Home -> Projects and Teams -> 'Source Directory'"

(Currently I am working with 2015, assuming if there is a solution it would be applicable on all versions*)

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a second account and tie your elevated privileges to that account?  Maybe like adm-alkykins?  Then when you need access to the additional privileges you could just login with that account instead?

Comment: For my scenario no (however for someone in similar situation may be viable solution).. For us, everything is tied to AD logins, so to tie to a different login I'd need an entirely new AD account. Along with that, each AD is tied to a developer license, so I wouldn't really be licensed properly under that login either.. Semantically may not matter as it would be me, but to MS and logins I think it would.

Comment: Yeah, what I was describing was what my company implemented.  It does require a second AD account.  I don't think you need a developer license for it though.  You could really just add the admin account into an elevated security group and when your primary account needs additional access, temporarily move the account into the appropriate TFS groups.